# SubSonic 3.0.0.2 - SimpleRepository Related Tables

Tags: subsonic3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subsonic 3 - SimpleRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176594/subsonic-3-simplerepository)

I've been looking all over StackOverflow and SubSonic Project and can't find how to perform one query using a SimpleRepository where I have a Product class with a Category.

Product contains a CategoryID and Category property to make up the POCO.  Category class of course contains CategoryID and CategoryName for the POCO.

When I try to do the following:

```
var repo = new SimpleRepository("myDBConnection");
var products = repo.All<Product>();

return View(products);
```

In the view I have an item.Category.CategoryName and that's where I get the runtime error.

Does SubSonic 3.0.0.3 resolve this issue?  Is there a workaround other than ActiveRecord and Linq Queries to create a new Anonymous Type object in the select?  Did I not find the question hidden away on S/O?

I'm starting to come to the end of my research of SubSonic for the project I'm working on and I'm probably going to start recommending a different ORM/DAL framework.  I've been running into a lot of problems where I really don't have enough documentation to go off of (SubSonicProject Docs or otherwise) to help me out and I'm starting to scramble for a new ***SOLID*** solution that will speed up my coding time to play catch up.